# How to realize this format in Latex?

Tags: fonts

How to realize the following format in LaTeX? I do not know how to correctly 
put the example in the LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: @CarLaTex, I thought it is a Latex problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you be a bit more specific what you mean by *format*? Do you just want to have the above text typeset in typewriter font (in this case, try `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}`? Or do you need a font as close as possible to the one in your example?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I've changed your tags because your problem has nothing to do with `biblatex` & Co. Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), you can modify your question clicking on the _edit_ button. The minimal working example is a little compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, see the previous link to know how to do it.

Comment: @gernot, I want to exactly realize the content I paste here. I do not know how to realize "1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4", and also I do not know how to realize "1 1 0 0  1 1  0 0 " . Can you put an answer here?

Comment: @brownwang Which aspect about "1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 " is hard to realize? The particular font? Or do you want to typeset something like a vector/tuple in mathematics and rather prefer a proportional font? A `verbatim` environment allows you to arrange material quickly in a what-you-see-is-what-you-get-fashion, but does not result in an adequately typeset document.

Comment: your last edit makes no sense.  Can someone roll this back?

Comment: @brownwang: If you don't want the image to be shown (for whatever reason), please create an alternative image that is okay to be shown so the question remains relevant to future visitors. Just removing makes the question useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `verbatim`, you get something like the following. Is this what you mean?

[image]

````
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{txtt}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
and your regressors look like this (2 conditions):

```
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

then the blocklables might look like this:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
```
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
````

Comment: let me have a try.